# Vectors that geodesically generate the same surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

Suppose that $\langle M,g \rangle$ is a complete, simply connected Riemannian symmetric space. The surface *geodesically generated* by a vector $\xi$ in $T_pM$ is the set of points lying on geodesics passing through $p$ that are orthogonal to $\xi$.

Suppose that $\xi$ and $\xi^\prime$ are vectors in $T_pM$ and $T_{p^\prime}M$ respectively that geodesically generate the same surface.

Does it follow that the vector obtained by parallel transporting $\xi$ along the geodesic connecting $p$ and $p^\prime$ is proportional to $\xi^\prime$?

Comment: is the use of the word "surface" here meant to imply a constraint on the dimension of $M$?

Comment: Oh, no it's not supposed to imply a constraint on the dimension of $M$. (Although I'm interested in the case of Lorentzian manifolds in particular. I don't think anything turns on this this though, so I posed the more general question.)

Comment: got it, nice question.

Comment: The surface $S$ geodesically generated by a vector can be a fairly nasty subset of $M$; just view a "chaotic" geodesic $S$ in some surface $M$ as geodesically generated by a vector orthogonal to $S$ at one point. Particularly, what does "parallel transport along _the_ geodesic connecting $p$ and $p'$ mean if $p = p'$ but $S$ is not a closed geodesic?

Comment: Good question. I think I probably want to add more conditions to rule that kind of strangeness out. But I don't have any ideas about how to do that at the moment. (Just so we're on the same page: by a "chaotic" geodesic, do you mean one that covers the whole surface?)

Comment: That might not be true even when $p = p'$. There might be some self intersecting geodesic. Then at the intersection point $p$, the two normal vectors are not parallel.

Comment: I wonder if your question has a positive answer assuming $(M,g)$ is a complete, simply connected Riemannian symmetric space.

Comment: Thanks Holonomia: yes, I think that is a good constraint to impose. I've edited the question.